# DNS Wildcard (linux)

Tags: domain-name-system, wildcard

Setup: A VLAN without internetaccess. When a user connects his/her computer with cable and tries to surf, the traffic will be directed to internal website.
How can I setup a DNS Wildcard so all traffic maps to internal website?

Answer (score 2):

DNS is not the right tool to achieve your goal IMHO.

This can be better done using the FW, doing a *REDIRECT* of all outbound traffic on web ports to your local web server, maybe you can consider adopting a *transparent Web Proxy* too ..

The implementation depends on you configuration, you can find tons of examples on the web; [here is](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-redirecting-network-traffic-a-new-ip-using-iptables) the first I got in google looking for **iptables redirect**

Comment: Thanks for your great answere. That's what I tried to recommend to the customer as well but that was not an option for them. They wanted it to be configured in the DNS, the users will never go to internet through this network.

Comment: +1 agree, this OP asks something which breaks DNS standard.Proxy is better solution